# OR-Tools: Adding Breaks to Pickup and Delivery Solution

Tags: python, or-tools

I am new to OR-Tools and have successfully created a solution for pickup and delivery problems with time windows and breaks using the following code:

```
# Breaks
# [START break_constraint]
# warning: Need a pre-travel array using the solver's index order.
node_visit_transit = [0] * routing.Size()
for index in range(routing.Size()):
    node = manager.IndexToNode(index)
    node_visit_transit[index] = data['service_time'][node]

break_intervals = {}
# Instantiate route start and end times to produce feasible times.
for v in range(manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()):
    if not data['vehicle_breaks'][v] is None:
        breakStartTime = data['vehicle_breaks'][v][0]
        breakEndTime = data['vehicle_breaks'][v][1]
        breakDuration = breakEndTime- breakStartTime
        break_intervals[v] = [
            routing.solver().FixedDurationIntervalVar(
                breakStartTime,  # start min
                breakStartTime + 500,  # start max
                breakDuration,  # duration: 10 min
                False,  # optional: no
                f'Break for vehicle {v}')
        ]
       
        time_dimension.SetBreakIntervalsOfVehicle(
            break_intervals[v],  # breaks
            v,  # vehicle index
            node_visit_transit)
```

However, although the breaks are correctly placed between the trips, they do not consider the pickup and delivery constraints. In other words, when a vehicle picks up a passenger, the break should not be allowed while the passenger is onboard. Unfortunately, the solution currently only schedules breaks when three passengers have been picked up but not yet dropped off.

How can we enforce the solver to take into account the pickup and drop-off constraints for breaks and only schedule a break when the vehicle's capacity is at its maximum value (i.e., when it does not have any passengers onboard)?"